# What would happen if a black hole swallowed a white hole?

Tags: black-holes, collision, white-holes

I’m just curious on this, if you can tell me then please do. Also don’t shame me for my bad question I’m just a curious little fella!

Comment: I’ll be here tomorrow January 24 at the time of the time stamp or close

Comment: Hi Jkt, welcome to Physics.SE! It would be helpful to see a little on what research you've already done and any ideas on what you think might happen.

Comment: I’ll also leave in an hour

Comment: Oh sorry hello!

Comment: I’m not as smart as 90% of the people on here are, but I think that it could possibly make the black hole even bigger due to the fact that it spews out items instead of swallow them.

Comment: If it would swallow the white hole and the white hole doesn’t collapse from that it may work like a core to the black hole feeding it until one of them collapsed.

Comment: Or make one of them collapse

Comment: Instantly......

Comment: @Jkt I think you’re a little hurt by your questions being closed or downvoted (I think this is your second account). Am I getting your feelings?

Comment: @Jkt  it is not a matter of smartness, but of level of background which needs a lot of study and elbow grease. You need to learn a lot of physics courses to be able to form questions in general relativity . Can you  understand the wiki article on white hole?https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_hole

Comment: or this https://www.technologyreview.com/s/420068/why-space-isnt-filled-with-white-holes/ White holes are not even in the first course of astrophysics here https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-901-astrophysics-i-spring-2006/syllabus/

Comment: This isn’t a duplicate, saying that if they collided isn’t the same as being swallowed...

Comment: Although i do agree with it associating with it...